# electron-builder doesn't recognize wine on Bitbucket Pipelines

Tags: node.js, docker, electron-builder, bitbucket-pipelines, wine

I'm building an electron app with `electron-builder`, hosted on Bitbucket.

I'm using a pipeline to build releases for Linux and Windows on every new commit on the master branch, using the provided Docker image which should contain all the necessary system dependencies:

bitbucket-pipelines.yml:

```yaml
image: electronuserland/builder:wine

pipelines:
    branches:
        master:
            - step:
                  name: "Build and Upload"
                  caches:
                      - node
                  script:
                      - npm i
                      - npm run release
```

package.json:

```json
"scripts": {
        "build": "rollup -c",
        "release": "npm run build && electron-builder -lw --x64",
           ...
     },
"build": {
        "icon": "public/favicon.png",
        "productName": "...",
        "files": [
            "public/**/*",
            "main.js"
        ],
        "win": {
            "target": [
                "nsis"
            ]
        },
        "linux": {
            "target": [
                "AppImage"
            ]
        }
    }
```

But every time, I get an error while executing `npm run release`:

```
 ⨯ wine is required, please see https://electron.build/multi-platform-build#linux  
  • Above command failed, retrying 0 more times
  ⨯ /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/app-builder-bin/linux/x64/app-builder exited with code ERR_ELECTRON_BUILDER_CANNOT_EXECUTE
```

I tried using a regular node Docker image and installing wine manually:

bitbucket-pipelines.yml:

```yaml
image: node

pipelines:
    branches:
        master:
            - step:
                  name: "Build and Upload"
                  caches:
                      - node
                  script:
                      - apt-get update
                      - apt-get install wine -y

                      - dpkg --add-architecture i386
                      - apt-get update
                      - apt-get install wine32 -y

                      - npm i
                      - npm run release
```

But I keep getting the same error.

How could I solve that, and build releases automatically with Bitbucket pipelines?

Comment: I would guess it's effect of [this](https://github.com/kata-containers/packaging/issues/513)

Comment: Have you considered using a publicly available custom image? or to just create one for that matter?

Comment: I've also addressed this issue over here. 
[Jira Ticket #5665](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/5665#issuecomment-1238402029)